# Posting parent_id in Ember.js and Rails 4 causes unpermitted parameters error. Remove or ignore?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

In ember.js (1.2) I am trying to POST a change to a child model but ember.js is including the parent_id in the POST. The parent_id is not a "permitted" parameter for my Rails 4 controller, however, so the POST fails with the following error.

```
Processing by ThingsController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"thing"=>{"title"=>"Test","location"=>"Baltimore","parent_id"=>nil}
Unpermitted parameters: parent_id
```

Since I don't want to make `parent_id` a permitted parameter for this model, how to I remove it from the POST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by removing the reference to parent in the child class. This turned out to not be necessary in my application since I often access children from the parent, but I never access the parent from the child.  In other words, the new model looks something like:

```
App.Thing = DS.Model.extend({

// commented out -> parent: DS.belongsTo('App.ParentThing'),

  title: DS.attr('String'),
  location: DS.attr('String')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same thing with a `createdAt` attribute. It was easily solved by overriding the ApplicationSerializer (or in your case, ThingSerializer):

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend
  serialize: (record, options) ->
    json = @_super(record, options)
    delete json.created_at
    json
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't cause you any problems to leave the value of `parent_id` in the `POST` parameters, so you can ignore it.

If you want to be clean about it (and not confuse other developers down the road), you should edit the form that is performing the `POST` and remove the form field that contains `parent_id`.

If you post your view code, I can held advise how to do the latter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You're correct, of course, it's just that a lot of the form information is hidden in ember.js. I was able to resolve it this morning by removing the `parent: DS.belongsTo('App.ParentModel')` from the child model.